# Identify files based on the ASCII characters in the binary

Tags: file, file-upload, binary, ascii, mime-types

I have a file uploader and in order to validate the file is actually of the type expected, I am inspecting the binary and checking the ASCII identifying characters (see the PDF example [here](http://filext.com/file-extension/PDF)).

The majority of files have an ASCII identifier, however some don't (like [XLS files](http://filext.com/file-extension/XLS))

How would I best identify these ones?

I see all have a hex values but as it stands, I don't currently have the capability of converting the binary data to Hex.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround...

I don't have a HEX converter, but I can convert both Binary and HEX to Base64 so that is what I am doing and comparing the Base64 output.